# Xamarin.Forms Unhandled Exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm trying CarouselView on my project. But when I Run my project,I get this error. [image]

Here is my xaml code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<base:HotelDetailPageXaml
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="XamarinCRM.Pages.Hotels.HotelDetailPage"
xmlns:statics="clr-namespace:XamarinCRM.Statics"
xmlns:base="clr-namespace:XamarinCRM.Pages.Hotels"
xmlns:hotelViews="clr-namespace:XamarinCRM.Views.Hotels"
xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:XamarinCRM.Localization"
xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
    Title="{Binding Hotel.Name}">
  <base:HotelDetailPageXaml.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="0">          
          <cv:CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Hotel.HotelImages}">
            <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout HeightRequest="200">
                  <Image HeightRequest="200" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding FullPath}"/>
                </StackLayout>
              </DataTemplate>
            </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
          </cv:CarouselView>
  </StackLayout>
  </base:HotelDetailPageXaml.Content>
</base:HotelDetailPageXaml>
```

And here is I called json service;

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<HotelModel>> GetHotelsAsync(bool includeLeads = false)
        {
            string path = "my service url";
            HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
            var task = await Client.GetAsync(path);
            var jsonString = await task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            List<HotelModel> hotelList = new List<HotelModel>();
            List<HotelImageModel> hotelImageList = new List<HotelImageModel>();
            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);   

                        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                        {
                            HotelImageModel hotelImage = new HotelImageModel();    
                            hotelImage.FullPath = json["data"][i]["HotelImages"][j]["FullPath"].Value;    
                            hotel.HotelImages.Add(hotelImage);
                        }
                    }
```

i is Hotel index number of for and j is Hotels' image index number

Comment: Looks like you have an exception. :-)
Please post the code that is failing and a full stack trace. Avoid posting text as a photo.

Comment: I have added more detail... Look at this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the forum of Xamarin report this error like a bug is the same error. 21 of June

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69483/why-does-carouselview-crash-on-android

what version of Xamarin you have installed? you try to install the latest version of xamarin?

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: I update the answer let me know if you solve the problem. Regards

Comment: Unfortunately, already I've seen this report but it's not like my error. I'm using Xamarin 4.1.1.

Comment: Try to update your version. You say that is not your error is exactly your error.  @ozmert75  Exception:

System.MethodAccessException: Method `Xamarin.Forms.BindingBase:TryGetSynchronizedCollection (System.Collections.IEnumerable,Xamarin.Forms.CollectionSynchronizationContext&)' is inaccessible from method `Xamarin.Forms.ItemsView/ItemsSourceProxy:get_SyncContext ()'

Comment: I'm trying it,I will share the results with you, thanks.

Comment: I gonna check the code later. try in the call of the service add a *try catch

Comment: I tried to show the photos into the listView,it works!, I think the problem carousel view additions.